# react-final-form with autocomplite component

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I have i dynamic form and having issue with Autocomplite component from material-ui when i connected with react-final-form-arrays, cant get the selected item value

here is form code

```
<Field
   name={`${name}`.product}
   list={products}
   component={AutocompleteField}
   label={'Products'}
/>
```

```
function ProductSelectField({list, label, dealer_id, stock_id, all_stocks, input, ...rest}) {

    const {name, onChange, ...restInput} = input;

    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const getProducts = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    }
    return (
        <Autocomplete
            {...rest}
            id="product"
            options={list}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
            defaultValue={list[0]}
            onChange={getProducts}
            inputValue={inputValue}
            onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                setInputValue(newInputValue);
            }}
            renderInput={(params) =>
                <TextField
                    {...restInput}
                    {...params}
                    label={label}
                    variant="outlined"
                />
            }
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any extra info or code box to go off of, it seems that you are not invoking the input's `onChange` hook to update the fields state. In your Autocomplete `prop.onChange`, you are invoking the `getProducts` hook but not where are you passing the value to the `onChange` hook.

```
- const {name, onChange, ...restInput} = input; //delete
     <TextField
       - {...restInput} //delete
         {...params}
         label={label}
         variant="outlined"
     />
// spread out the entire input prop into the Autocomplete
<Autocomplete
    {...input}
    {... rest of your props}
/>
```

[These Docs on React-Final-Form](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldRenderProps#inputname) shows you what the `input` prop passes down and it shows how it does all the work for you.

However, I use the Autocomplete from material-ui as well and understand you want to control the local state at the same time. Refactor your `getProducts` hook to update both.

```js
const getProducts = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
        input.onChange(event); // the event will carry over because 'text' and 'select' inputs both return the 'event.target.value' without any extra logic for the Field component.
    }
```